# Check if video file is ready for playing while being downloaded from torrent

Tags: python, video, gstreamer, kivy, libtorrent

I am  quite new in python.
I have written a program which downloads a video file through torrent, using libtorrent. I have set it to sequential download so all the parts are downloaded in right order, for watching that video while it is being downloaded.
The problem I get is that the file is not available for playing immediately after download has started. Sometimes there should be downloaded 10mb, sometimes 30mb before video view could be started.
My thoughts are, that this is because of some metadata are missing.
My question is about the way to check whether file could be played or not. Any suggestions on achieving this? I have searched a lot but not found anything yet.
I am using python 2.7 (2.7 because of its compatibility with libtorrent), libtorrent, kivy framework 1.8 and built-in video player, which uses gstreamer as far as i know.
Source code could be checked at github:https://github.com/dpitkevics/stream-ies?files=1
Important files are main.py, lib/downloader.py
Thank You in advance guys :)

Comment: a try/except in a while loop?

Comment: On mkv, for example, some metadata is stored at the end of file, so you aren't just fine only with sequential download. Another problem with sequential download is that slow peers can make a hole inside your downloaded data. You should somehow handle this situation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a metadata extraction tool, such as [Hachoir](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/1.3.3). If the tool is able to successfully read the metadata, chances are the file is good to go. BUT - you don't necessarily want to start playback at that point. You need to buffer as well. The metadata will provide you with the content length; with the file size and download speed from the torrent you can calculate how much buffer is needed to ensure seamless playback. If you buffer properly, and the streams in the container are interleaved, this should ensure you always have the necessary data to start playback.

Comment: Great suggestion, I will try it out and accept answer if it will succeed for me :)

Comment: Thank You! I tried it out and it worked like a charm - no metadata as long as video is not playable. Now, I will need to calculate buffer and thats all. Thanks :)